# Electron-builder release tries to publish to Github and complains about GH_Token

Tags: electron, electron-builder

running the `release` script without `publish` option tries to publish the build to GitHub ( and fails while complaining about not being able to find GHToken! )

`Error: GitHub Personal Access Token is not set, neither programmatically, nor using env "GH_TOKEN"`

---

Setting `"publish": "never"` will fail also complaining about not being able to find module `electron-publisher-never`!

`Error: Cannot find module 'electron-publisher-never'`

---

It all happens while the project is built but build scripts exits non-zero!

I'm using the latest version of electron-builder.
my build script:

```
 "build": {
"appId": "eu.armand.[****]",
"copyright": "Copyright © 2017 mim_Armand",
"productName": "[****]",
"mac": {
  "publish": "never",
  "category": "public.app-category.[****]",
  "icon": "assets/icons/mac/icon.icns"
}
```

Any idea what's going on or if I'm doing it wrong?!

,m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try building with

```
"build": "electron-builder --publish never"
```

to never publish.

Comment: Hey Ajey,
I have tried that too, in addition, The main problem is when the build happens in a CI environment,
It's not a big deal tho as I'd need to set-up the publish step eventually, just didn't make sense that it was the default behaviour

Comment: Btw adding `--publish never` seems to have no effect either, still tries to publish, even when ran locally, I think it may be a bug with electron-builder or one of its packages or dependencies

Comment: Oh! my bad, I don't know how I made such mistake!
I was trying to add the `--publish never` flag after `npm run build` instead of adding it to the build npm script like you showed!
probably because I'm working on several different projects atm (Java/Spring, NG4, React/Redux, Electron, Alexa, and CI pipelines for all of them sh#*t!) my brain is kind of numb!
Thanks again! :+1:

Answer (score 1):

**rename your script** to something else.
if the script name is `release` → publish is set to `always`

the [documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/publish) states this:

> CLI --publish option values:
>   ...
>   If npm script named `release`, — always.
>   Add to scripts in the development package.json:
>   `"release": "build"`
>   and if you run `yarn release`, a release will be drafted (if doesn’t
>   already exist) and **artifacts published**.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way, because I didn't need to put it in any repository

```json
"build":{
    "appId": "XXX",
    "productName": "XXX",
    "directories":{
      "output": "build"
    },
    "win":{
     "target": "nsis",
     "publish" : []
    }
}
```

https://www.electron.build/configuration/publish